# Drawing JSON tree with Canvas or SVG

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, svg, draw

I need to create a state machine parser, I've already done and it validates a word with a given automaton, also it generates a tree of the analysis it has done, after all the only thing I do is counting the number total of final states it has reached and if it is more than 1 then the word is valid, the problem is that now I have to draw the paths followed to get into each one of the final states.

[Transition table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1xK5.png)

If I validate the word "ab" this will generate a json object with this:

```
{
 "a": {
      "0": {
           "b": [
                "0",
                "1",
                "2"
                ]
            },
      "3": {
           "b": false
            }
        }
 }
```

So, the real question is here how to pass from this JSON

To this:

[Example of the final draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbA6M.png)

Here you can see what is all the paths generated, I just count the total of Final states and that indicates if is a valid word, So all the paths have to be drawed and also the correct paths (those who end in a final state) have to be marked diferent so it is easy to see.

Also if you have a better idea for the structure of the json object that makes easy to draw it is wellcome, I don't have problem on modifying the function to generate a diferent structure.

I wold like to do it with Canvas or SVG but I have not much idea of how can i do that, this is going to be a free tool for learning how this states machines work.

Thank you for your help!.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. You can do it from scratch (I would personally recommend using SVG rather than Canvas), or you could use a library such as Raphael.js or D3.js (or probably many others).

Comment: If you have time for a learning curve check out the d3 library